# Adding a unit to a transfinite aggregate

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Link: http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/cantor1.pdf

On page 103, there is an "aggregate given by the totality of finite cardinal numbers $v$" where $v$ is defined as an "unlimited series" on page 99.

So, I assume that the aforementioned aggregate originally consists of all possible--and in fact, unlimited amount of--units.

Why then, upon inserting another unit $e_0$ into the original aggregate on page 104, is it possible to create a union aggregate that is equivalent to the original aggregate, when the original aggregate was complete in the first place? It seems as though the new element $e_0$ that was added was indeed a new element, but it does not fall into the category of a "finite cardinal number" as required by the definition of the original aggregate, since I am assuming that the original aggregate already consists of all possible elements, even though those elements are unlimited.

In other words, to me it doesn't make sense to say that a set consists of {1, 2, 3, 4, ...} and then later say, oh, and there is an additional element. What would this additional element be? I can't think of an element that would "fit" so to speak, since all of the elements are already in the original aggregate.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It is a "standard" result of [cardinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#History) proved by Cantor:

> $\aleph_0+1=\aleph_0$.

In general, we have that [the set of *positive* integers and the set of integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_set#Formal_overview_without_details) have the same cardinality, because we may exhibit a bijection between them: $n ↔ 2n$.

The Cantor example can be rephrased as follows:

> let $\{ \nu \} = \{ 1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$ and let $\{ \nu \}_0= \{ \nu \} \cup \{ 0 \} = \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$.

Tthe two aggregates are equivalent, i.e. the two sets have the same cardinality.

This property is not true for *finite* aggregates; we cannot find a bijection between e.g. $\{ 1,2 \}$ and $\{ 0, 1, 2 \}$.